# Android specific google authorization

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-4, google-api, openid

I write web site "mysite.com" with uses ASP.NET MVC 4

Authorization on site by google OAuth "xxxx@yyyy.com"

All work correct. In site database created account associated with google account.

I need login in this site from android device with "xxxx@yyyy.com" account (Account added in device)

I try

```java
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(MainActivity.this, "xxxx@yyyy.com", "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN);
```

I don`t undertand how link together GoogleAuthUtil and "mysite.com" and "xxxx@yyyy.com"

Help please sample or links

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Google+ API in Google APIs Console. All instructions are already detailed in the Google+ Android API docs: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

Comment: Hey @Andrew, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? I have enabled the appropriate APIs in the Google APIs Console https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151